# How much of core is used for nfs transfer

Tags: pi-2, raspbian-wheezy, nfs

So I am debating on whether or not to use my one core or quad core pi as the nfs root for my pi cluster. I do not know much about nfs and am wondering if the amount of cores matter. I appreciate any input.

Comment: The performance is going to be more limited by the network transfer speed. If you are build a new system start with the Jessie image. Wheezy is end of life, and won't be getting any updates.

Comment: @Milliways I actually started with Jessie and could not figure out for the life of me how to set a static ip but figured it out no problem on wheezy. But you are saying that one or four cores won't make to much a difference?

Comment: If you really want to set a static address see http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip/37921#37921 All I/O on the Pi (USB & ethernet) goes through one chip. The Ethernet is 100Mbps which limits the speed. If you were were doing something processor intensive it may make a difference, but serving files is not.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need multiple cores. NFS transfers usually only use one CPU/core. You will have already reached your Ethernet connection's limit before you hit your CPU limit. It only matters when you heavily encrypt your transfers or when the CPU is already at 100%.

Your single-core pi is more than enough. Even a Pi Zero is way more than enough. But, it wouldn't hurt to use a Pi 2 if you are also running lots of services on it.